# how can i create a autocomplete textinput in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, desktop-application

This is my .py file i need to create a autocomplete textinput i have created textinput and RV class which subclass recycleview and dropdown but the problem is its not droping down it is  dropping up to and when this is dropping up the textinput is minimized this is the python file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty,ListProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import sqlite3
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from collections import OrderedDict

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleBoxLayout):
''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
    ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
       self.index = index
       return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
        rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):

           return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
           return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

   def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
    ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
       self.selected = is_selected




class ListcreationWindow(BoxLayout):

    code_inp = ObjectProperty()
    flt_list = ObjectProperty()
    word_list = ListProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListcreationWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cart = []
        self.qty = []
        self.total = 0.00




class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
   code_inp = ObjectProperty()
   rv = ObjectProperty()
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
   code_inp = ObjectProperty()
   flt_list = ObjectProperty()
   word_list = ListProperty()
# this is the variable storing the number to which the look-up will start
   starting_no = NumericProperty(3)
   suggestion_text = ''


   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(MyTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   def on_text(self, instance, value):
    # find all the occurrence of the word

       matches = [self.word_list[i] for i in range(len(self.word_list)) if
       self.word_list[i][:self.starting_no] ==  value[:self.starting_no]]

       display_data = []
       for i in matches:
           display_data.append({'text': i})
    #ensure the size is okay
       if len(matches) <= 10:
           self.parent.height = (50 + (len(matches) * 20))
       else:
           self.parent.height = 240

   def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
       if self.suggestion_text and keycode[1] == 'tab':
           self.insert_text(self.suggestion_text + ' ')
           return True
       return super(MyTextInput, self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)

class RV(DropDown):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        notes = ['Features', 'Suggestions', 'Abreviations', 'Miscellaneous']
        for note in notes:
           btn = Button(text='%r' % note, size_hint_y=None, height=30)
           btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.select(btn.text))
           self.add_widget(btn)
        mainbutton = MyTextInput()
        mainbutton.bind(on_text=self.open)
        self.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))




 class ListcreationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ListcreationWindow()

 if __name__=='__main__':
    ListcreationApp().run()
```

This is my .kv file which is used to create the ui the RV widget is created here

```
<SelectableLabel>:
# Draw a background to indicate selection
    color: 0,0,0,1
    canvas.before:
       Color:
           rgba: (0, 0, 1, 5) if self.selected else (1, 1, 1, 1)
       Rectangle:
           pos: self.pos
           size: self.size
<MyTextInput>:
   readonly: False
   multiline: False
<RV>:

   bar_width: 1
   bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
   bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
   viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
   SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
       default_size: dp(50), dp(30)
       default_size_hint: 1, None
       size_hint_y: None
       height: self.minimum_height
       orientation: 'vertical'
       multiselect: False
       touch_multiselect: True


<FlatButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    font_size: 14
<ListcreationWindow>:
    id:main_win
    orientation:'vertical'
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    canvas.before:
        Color:
           rgba:(1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
           size:self.size
           pos:self.pos
   BoxLayout:
       id:header
       size_hint_y:None
       canvas.before:
           Color:
               rgba:(.06, .45, .45, 1)
           Rectangle:
               size:self.size
               pos:self.pos
       Label:
           text: "Nadeem POS system"
           size_hint_x: .9
           bold: True
           color:(1,1,1,1)
       FlatButton:
           id:loggedin_user
           text:'nadeem'
           color:(1,1,1,1)
   BoxLayout:
       id:current
       size_hint_y:None
       height:50
       canvas.before:
           Color:
               rgba:(.06, .45, .45, 1)
           Rectangle:
               size:self.size
               pos:self.pos
       Button:
           text:'Current Item'
           background_normal:''
           background_color:(.06, .32 , .32, 1)
           size_hint_x: .4

       Button:
           id:cur_product
           text:'Default Product'
           background_normal:''
           background_color:(.06, .4 , .4, 1)
       Button:
           id:cur_price
           text:'0.00'
           background_normal:''
           background_color:(.06, .65 , .65, 1)
           size_hint_x: .2
    BoxLayout:
        padding:10
    BoxLayout:
        id: product_details
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_x: .8
        spacing:10
        BoxLayout:
            id:product_labels
            size_hint_y:None
            height:40
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:(.06,.45,.45, 1)
                Rectangle:
                    size:self.size
                    pos:self.pos
            FlatButton:
                text:'Qty'
                size_hint_x: .1
            FlatButton:
                text:'Product Code'
                size_hint_x: .3
            FlatButton:
                text:'Product Name'
                size_hint_x: .2
            FlatButton:
                text:'Price'
                size_hint_x: .1
        BoxLayout:
            id:product_inputs
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 30
            spacing:5
            TextInput:
                id:qty_inp
                size_hint_x:.1
            MyLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: 2
                code_inp: code_inp
                MyTextInput:
                    id: code_inp
                    size_hint_x:1
                    multiline:False
                    size_hint_y:1
                    on_text_validate:root.update_purchases()
                RV:
                    id:rv
                    size_hint_x:1
            TextInput:
                id:disc_inp
                size_hint_x:.2
            TextInput:
                id:price_inp
                size_hint_x:.1
        BoxLayout:
            id:add_to_cart
            orientation:"vertical"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:30
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                    Rectangle:
                        size:self.size
                        pos:self.pos
                Label:
                    text:'Code'
                    size_hint_x:.2
                Label:
                    text:'Product name'
                    size_hint_x:.3
                Label:
                    text:'Qty'
                    size_hint_x:.1
                Label:
                    text:'Price'
                    size_hint_x:.1
            GridLayout:
                id: products
                cols: 1
    BoxLayout:
        id:preview
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint_x:.2

        TextInput:
            id:receipt_preview
            readonly:True
            text:"\t\t\t\tThe Collector\n\t\t\t\t123 Main St\n\t\t\t\tKnowhere, Space\n      \n\t\t\t\tTel:(555)-123-456\n\t\t\t\tReceipt No:\n\t\t\t\t Gate:\n\n"

        Button:
            id:button_pro
            text:'Process'
            size:75,40
            size_hint: None,None
BoxLayout:
    id:footer
    size_hint_y:None
    height:30
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:(.06,.47,.47,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size
    Label:
        text:'maintained by nadeem'
```

Comment: Please edit your post to correct the indentation in both the python code and the `kv` file.

Comment: Also, please simplify so we don't need your database in order to run it. I guess I'm asking for a [mcve].

Comment: there is no problem in indentation but the Recyclerview or the RV class is also a drop down which is not going downwards its going upwards and minimizing the text input

Comment: my code is with indentation

Comment: the code is now edited and the database part is removed

Comment: Can you just use a `DropDown` instead of a `RecycleView`? The `RecycleView` is intended for very large numbers of items. If your matches are not numbering in the thousands, I suspect a `DropDown` would suffice.

Comment: i have changed it to dropdown still its dropping up not dropping down

Comment: I can't check your code without seeing your code.

Comment: https://github.com/NadeemRawther/BillingKivy its the github link of my full code the software starts from src/BillingKiv/main.py and starts from there to other pages

Comment: I don't see where you applied my answer anywhere in your code.

Comment: its in OperatorWindow folder operatorwindow.py the RV class is what is used

Comment: So, you still have not applied my answer. I have edited my answer below, with more specific suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hacked version of `DropDown` that lets you specify if you want the `DropDown` to always be below the `Widget` that it is attached to.

```
class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
    force_below = BooleanProperty(False)  # if True, DropDown will be positioned below attached to Widget
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.do_not_reposition = False  # flag used to avoid repositioning recursion

    def _reposition(self, *largs):
        if self.do_not_reposition:
            return
        super(CustomDropDown, self)._reposition(*largs)
        if self.force_below:
            self.make_drop_below()

    def make_drop_below(self):
        self.do_not_reposition = True  # avoids recursion triggered by the changes below
        if self.attach_to is not None:
            wx, wy = self.to_window(*self.attach_to.pos)
            self.height = wy  # height of DropDown will fill window below attached to Widget
            self.top = wy  # top of DropDown will be at bottom of attached to Widget
        self.do_not_reposition = False  # now turn auto repositioning back on
```

To use it, you can just call `CustomDropDown(force_below=True)`. Of course, if the space below the attached to `Widget` to the bottom of the `Window` is too small, this will not be useable. A more general approach would allow specification of below, above, or normal choices for positioning.

This can be used in your `MyTextInput` class:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    code_inp = ObjectProperty()
    flt_list = ObjectProperty()
    word_list = ListProperty()
    # this is the variable storing the number to which the look-up will start
    starting_no = NumericProperty(3)
    suggestion_text = ''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.dropdown = CustomDropDown(force_below=True)
        notes = ['Features', 'Suggestions', 'Abreviations', 'Miscellaneous']
        for note in notes:
            # when adding widgets, we need to specify the height manually (disabling
            # the size_hint_y) so the dropdown can calculate the area it needs.
            btn = Button(text='%r' % note, size_hint_y=None, height=30)

            # for each button, attach a callback that will call the select() method
            # on the dropdown. We'll pass the text of the button as the data of the
            # selection.
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))

            # then add the button inside the dropdown
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        # one last thing, listen for the selection in the dropdown list and
        # assign the data to the button text.
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self, 'text', x))

    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        # only open DropDown if it is not already open and this TextInput is displayed
        if self.dropdown.parent is None and self.get_parent_window() is not None:
            self.dropdown.open(self)

    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if self.suggestion_text and keycode[1] == 'tab':
            self.insert_text(self.suggestion_text + ' ')
            return True
        return super(MyTextInput, self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)
```

Also need to comment out the `RV` in `operator.kv`:

```
                MyLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    spacing: 2
                    code_inp: code_inp
                    MyTextInput:
                        id: code_inp
                        size_hint_x:1
                        multiline:False
                        size_hint_y:1
                        on_text_validate:root.update_purchases()
#                    RV:
#                        id:rv
#                        size_hint_x:1
```

This is basically just a proof of concept. Obviously, more logic is required.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i am new to kivy it helped me a lot